# Vertx EventBus send() and request() blocking WorkerVerticle

Tags: vert.x

I am trying to handle situation in Vertx when I have MainVerticle and WorkerVerticle (deployed from MainVerticle).
In 'start()' method of WorkerVerticle I run request() or send() methods on EventBus and it is a blocking code (I see that it doesn't go the next line...).

```
DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions().setSendTimeout(1000);
vertxEventBus.send("aaddress", "object", options);
```

I would like to handle situation when the consumer for "aaddress" doesn't exist - in this case I would like the vertxEventBus.send(...)/vertxEventBus.request(...) methods to not be blocking but throw some exception or be handled on onFailure(...). The code should 'go' to the next line and block the WorkerVerticle thread. Is it possible in Vertx?

Answer (score 1):

I made a stupid mistake and IntelliJ was not helpful in debugging. vertxEventBus was null so it didn't work. However I do not understand why IntelliJ didn't post stack trace with NullPointerException for my code, instead the whole unit test was run without any visible exception.
After I initialized vertxEventBus correctly the code started to work normally.